# Объявление массивов в ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp, visual-basic

Как в ASP при объявлении массива сразу задать его значения? В некоторых руководствах описано как

```
Dim a()={1,2,3}
```

но это не проходит (вызывает ошибку).

Answer (score 2):

Возможно нужно написать так -

```
Dim a() as integer = {1,2,3}
```

Comment: в продолжение выше сказанного и предупреждая вопрос еще дальнейший)) <pre>  Dim b(,) As String = {{"аа", "аб"}, {"ба", "бб"}}</pre> для двухмерного

Comment: Подробнее здесь: "[Практическое руководство. Инициализация переменных массива в Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y13tek7e.aspx)". Не думаю, что в работе с массивами в ASP.NET есть какая-то специфика.

Comment: Спасибо, но

HTTP 500.100 - Внутренняя ошибка сервера - ошибка ASP
Internet Information Services

Тип ошибки:
Ошибка компиляции Microsoft VBScript (0x800A0401)
Предполагается наличие окончания инструкции
/abit.html, line 10, column 8
Dim a() as integer = {1,2,3}
-------^

Предполагается наличие константы целого типа
/abit.html, line 12, column 6
Dim b(,) As String = {{"??", "??"}, {"??", "??"}}
-----^

Comment: А так

    Dim numbers = New Integer() {1, 2, 4, 8}

?

Comment: так тоже пробовал. нет. Оно категорически не приемлет знак =

Обращаю внимание, что это именно ASP а не ASP.NET.
И это VBScript, а не Visual Basic

Comment: А если так: 

    Dim a


    a = Array(1,2,3,4)

Comment: ПРОБЛЕМА РЕШЕНА!

Правильный синтаксис:

a = Array (1,2,3)

То есть, в ASP хоть и бейсик, но синтаксис в некоторых местах на манер javascript

Запоминаем: ASP - не ASP.NET, а VBScript - не Visual Basic

Нумерация массивов - от 0, т.е. a(0) - 1, a(1) - 2 и т.д.

Comment: Так как в моем предыдущем комментарии верное решение не могли бы Вы принять ответ как правильный.

>>Запоминаем: ASP - не ASP.NET, а VBScript - не Visual Basic

и тем не менее в метках Вы указали как ASP.NET так и Visual Basic !

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил ваш комментарий, он был скрыт, а я только сейчас увидел, что не все комменты показываются сразу. Решения я нашел сам, но ваше абсолютно правильное.

Метки ASP.NET и Visual Basic присваивал не я, я вообще не ставил никаких меток. Не знаю кто ставил, видимо, администратор :)

Answer (score 0):

В Classic ASP (VBScript) делается так:

```
Dim arr
arr = Array(1, 4, 19)
```

В ASP.NET (VB.NET) делается так:

```
Dim arr as int32() = {1, 6, 10}
```